# Cannot load shared libraries in gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm trying to run application in `gdb` but it seem's I have problem with debbuger. I cannot load shared libraries all the ways I've tried to.

Libraries are stored in `/usr/local/lib64` and environment is ok:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib64:/home/user/lib
```

When I run appllication in `gdb`, the following happens:

```
(gdb) set solib-search-path /usr/local/lib64
(gdb) show solib-search-path The search path for loading non-absolute
shared library symbol files is /usr/local/lib64. 
(gdb) info sharedlibrary No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

and I can't set any breakpoint to debug my app, but at the same time app is running ok in gdb and debug symbols are reading from binaries!

I guess, the problem is related with permissions but don't know exactly where it is.

To avoid any misunderstanding, I should notice that my application runs good and I don't have any troubles with access to shared libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run appllication in gbd, the following happens:

You haven't actually *run* the application yet, so "no shared libraries loaded at this time" is correct and *expected*.

You need to actually execute the GDB `run` command.

**Update:**

> I can execute run command and that's a strange thing.

No, it's not a strange thing. You don't have a problem, everything is working as expected.

I am guessing that your *real* problem is that you can't set breakpoints in shared libraries that your application is using. A solution for *that* problem is to do this:

```
gdb /path/to/app
(gdb) start

# Application stops at main.
# You can now set any breakpoint you want.
(gdb) break foo.c:123
```

Comment: @mortalland You are doing a poor job explaining what your real problem is. Answer updated with my current guess of what it might be.

Comment: Yes, As @EmployedRussian said, executing run command is not at all a strange thing. Your shared libraries(.so files) will be loaded when you execute and run your application.